# How to export all methods in an unmanaged dll to managed c#?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, unmanaged

I have a c++ dll with 10 methods and 12 properties, is there any way or any application to export the p/invoke format of the methods to be used in c# ? 
I have use OLE Viewer to inspect all the methods, for example :

> [id(0x00000013)] 
>   BSTR GetCPUID( 
>                  short BeginAddress, 
>                  short EndAddress);

but i dont know how to use this function in c#.

Comment: DLLs do not have properties... It looks like you want to use COM object provided by the DLL, in which case it is absolutely different question.

Comment: sorry for my bad explanation , you are right the file is an OCX file. please help if you can.

Comment: You are looking for "COM interop", search for it or start with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: wow , that was great Alexei Levenkov , but when i go for it try to make an instance from my object I'll get this error : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0CA5A93D-F6BD-4398-809A-9F767276EF77} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Comment: it seems that i have to register the ocx file, but in my case i can not do that, i have to use the methods directly

Comment: Create separate question with concrete sample code and correct tags. Someone will answer. I'd strongly recommend spending more than couple minutes at least scanning though articles/answers here since using COM objects from C# is a common task for lot of people (not me).